# Except Tank and Dozer, was anyone from Morpheus' crew in Zion before Mr. Anderson joined them?

Tags: the-matrix

On the Nebuchadnezzar, other than the two naturally born humans Tank and Dozer, were any of the crew ever in Zion *before* they unjacked Mr. Anderson to join them? I think Morpheus must have been in Zion once or multiple times since he was the captain, he was rather old compared to his crewmates I guess and he had the codes agent Smith desired. What about Mr. Reagan, Mouse, Switch, Apoc and Mrs. Moss?

I guess Mr. Reagan has never been in Zion because he was unhappy outside the Matrix which probably wouldn't be the case if he lived in Zion. And perhaps Mouse was too young to visit the city as yet. But I think all the hoverships visit Zion once in a time.

Comment: Why would you think they *wouldn't* have been in Zion? Why would Reagan/Cypher necessarily be happy if he had been there? He still wouldn't get steaks or all the things he craved.

Comment: I think we can reasonably assume that Morpheus' crew have been to Zion on many occasions, re-supplying the ship, training and just spending time in the city. Probably it's quite unusual that Neo is immediately assigned to a ship and heads right back in.]

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think in Zion they eat better food than the one on the hovercraft, maybe even steaks or something. To your first question: when Tank talked with Mr. Anderson about Zion he said something like "if you get old enough you might get the chance to see it" though I dunno how the quote is in English. This implies the crew wasn't in Zion as yet or rarely, as if it were exceptional to visit Zion.

Comment: @John - I doubt they eat steaks. Do you see any cows?

Comment: @John - The quote is "*You live long enough, you might even see it.*"

Comment: @Valorum At least they eat bread there as stated in your answer.

Comment: @John - They did so when Morpheus was a child. They may have stopped doing so in later years.

Comment: @Valorum Why would they? One would expect Zion improves over time, not retards.

Comment: @John - The bread was made with stores of wheat that had been grown outside of Zion. The machines destroyed the wheat fields 40+ years before the events of the The Matrix.

Comment: @Valorum Wait, what stores? I thought there can't grow anything outside because the Sun is blocked?? (I've only seen the movies)

Comment: @John - http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034230/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/paulcMiller1a.html

Comment: @Valorum Very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I think we can reasonably assume that all of the ship's crew have their own apartments somewhere in Zion.

Morpheus certainly spent time in Zion. We see him as a much younger man at a Zionese feast in the webcomic *[The Miller's Tale](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Miller%27s_Tale)*.

[image]

Trinity has been there sufficiently often that she has her own (decorated) room. Sparsely furnished, but certainly not just a hotel room.

[image]
**<sub><sup>Concept Images courtesy of The Zion Archive</sup></sub>**

Comment: Specifically I wonder whether Mr. Reagan ever has been to Zion. Obviously not, otherwise I think he would quit his job on the Nebuchadnezzar and live another life in Zion, and perhaps find another woman and found a family.

Comment: @John - He stays on the Neb because he's besotted with Trinity. I think we can reasonably assume he's been to Zion regularly (for resupply trips, leave, etc)

Comment: He didn't really love Mrs. Moss, it was rather lust, and he said "I _thought_ that I love you". I think Mr. Reagan would rather want to become a senator in Zion than being a crew member on the hovercraft. Do you have a source for frequent visits to Zion by the Neb (in contrast to Tank's statement which implies it was rather rare)?

Comment: @John - The various ships come in for docking regularly. There are several comments about how rare it is to have all of the hovercraft in dock at the same time, implying that it's not rare to have more than one.

Comment: Do we know how long Mr. Reagan and Mouse (the youngest crew member) were ejected from the Matrix, at the time Mr. Anderson joined them?

Comment: @John - Depending on various sources, Reagan/Cypher was ejected as an adult. We have no back-story on Mouse at all.

Comment: You see, Mr. Reagan could have been (one of) the newest member(s) and thus perhaps wouldn't have had the chance to see Zion as yet.

Comment: Cypher has been out for nine years. (*"**Cypher:** *You know, I know this steak doesn’t exist. I know that when I put it in my mouth, the Matrix is telling my brain that it is juicy and delicious. After nine years, you know what I realize? Ignorance is bliss."*) During that time they absolutely would have had to come in to resupply, presumably multiple times. Think "submarine".

Comment: Oh well, indeed, I guess you're right.